# Laravel: How to login with Hash password in laravel applicaiton

Tags: php, laravel, hash, laravel-5

Here is the scenario:

I have made a random hash password and I send it to user mail with login details(eg. mail). User got the mail but he couldn't login in site with that hash password. How do I solve this?

Here is my controller:

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
           $user->password=Hash::make(str_random(4));

         $user->update($request->all( ));    

        Mail::send('mail', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
                $m->from('xxxxxx.com', 'xxx');
                $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Thanks!');
        });
    }
```

Any possible suggestion please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the password to a variable before hashing and send it to the end user.

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user                    = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->passwordToBeSend  = str_random(4);
    $user->password          = Hash::make($newPassword);
    $user->update($request->all( )); 
    Mail::send('mail', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('xxxxxx.com', 'xxx');
            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Thanks!');
    });
}
```

Make sure you send your new password ($newPassword) to the mail sending block. or just assign to the $user as new object like '$user->passwordTomail = $newPassword;'

Comment: How do I do it? means how do I send the $newPassword in mail.blade.php file through controller?

Comment: You can pass it as array in to the blade, and via `use` block in the mail sending closure (same way as you are passing `user' in the your code). Anyway, you can use the above block (see updated answer) and replace {{$password}} with {{$passwordToBeSend }} in your blade template.

Answer (score 0):

You need you write you own login function instead of using the one laravel provided. Basically just fetch the user from database and compare it directly without another hashing

```
function login($id, $password) {    
    $user = User::where('id',$id)->where('password',$password)->first();
    if($user){
         Auth::login($user);
    } 
}
```

However, it is not a good practice as laravel already provide build-in password reset function that you can just type`php artisan make:auth` to use. you can check their [official document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart) for more information